# Check Constraint using UDF that check more than one table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a UDF constraint in SQL Server 2012. Basically to validate that I don't allow to have for example three columns with the same value, but one of the column comes from another table, the other two come from the same. So how can I create a UDF constaint to basically check this? I can send two parameters for one table but the third one? Is there any other idea  for this?

Comment: Just don't do it. Seriously. Use triggers. Just take a gander at [this first page of results here](http://www.google.com/search?q=check+constraint+udf+kuznetsov). Bad news.

Comment: Ok I can use INSTEAD OF trigger, but in my case how can I check one of the values that is in another table?

Comment: You would use a join to look at values in another table. You would join using the inserted and/or deleted virtual tables.

Comment: With a join maybe? Or an EXISTS?

Comment: So, an INSTEAD OF triggers will work much better than a constraint using a UDF?

Comment: Yes, though you may need an after trigger, since an instead of trigger has additional limitations. We don't know nearly enough about you database to know for sure. But we can assure you: when you think constraint + UDF, there is absolutely a better solution, every time.